# javascript: how to implement animation?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, animation, jquery-animate

I'm using Google Maps Javascript API V3 in my project. I want to move a marker from one postion to another position animately. I can update a mark's postion by

```
marker.setPosition(newPosition)
```

but how to smoothly move the marker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var startPos, curPos, endPos, delta; // set these values
var interval;

curPos = startPos;

function move() {
    marker.setPosition(curPos);

    if ( curPos < endPos ) {
       if ( curPos + delta > endPos ) curPos = endPos - curPos;
       else curPos += delta;

       setTimeout(move, interval);
    }
}

move();
```

`curPos`, `startPos` `endPos`, and `delta` are instances of `google.maps.LatLng`